beamer export with cite and macro
I am creating my presentations with orgmode and export via a template to beamer/tex/pdf. This works quite nice.
Though for referencing images I am using usually a tex macro to put the reference to the lower right corner with a smaller font
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\begin{textblock*}{12.5cm}(0.2cm,8.45cm)
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=0.5cm,right]{framesource}
\usebeamerfont{framesource}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesource} Source: {#1}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{textblock*}}

And then I am using in my orgmode slides \source{something,2022}.
To connect this macro with bibtex I have to use
+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\source{\cite{silvestriModellingTurbulentHeat2021}}
+END_EXPORT

but I would actually like to use the orgmode way, e.g.
\source{[cite:@silvestriModellingTurbulentHeat2021]}

but this way the cite does not get translated correctly.
Does anyone have an idea how I can use the orgmode-cite approach in combination with a latex macro?
